# jquery-bootgrid:Getting values from hidden column rows

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery-bootgrid as a data grid manager.Is it now possible to get values from hidden columns?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It's almost definitely possible, but without any code to work off of, it is impossible to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: I read the "Command Buttons Example" and my problem solved :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and accept the answer so that others may benefit. :)

Comment: thx to remind me, I would to do that.

Answer (score 0):

console.log($(this).data("row-id"));

var $tr_parent=$(this).parents("tr").first();

console.log($tr_parent.children('td').eq(3).text());

this code works good

jut td count start 0 to X

you calculate td number contain data and get data by number of td

Answer (score 0):

To get the hidden column row value, you need to add `data-identifier="true"` for that column. Then if it is on the row click, you can get the value by `var id= $(this).data("row-id")`;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
On selecting the Edit button:

```
    grid.find(".command-edit").on("click", function(e)
    {
        var ele =$(this).parent();
        var FirstColumn = ele.siblings(':first').html();
        var SecondColumn = ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html();
        var ThirdColumn = ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(3)').html();
    }
```